# Algorithm for finding similar words

Tags: algorithm

In order to support users learning English, I want to make a multiple-choice quiz using the vocabulary that the user is studying.

For example, if the user is learning "angel" then I need an algorithm to produce some similar words such as "angle" and "angled"

Another example, if the user is learning "accountant" then I need an algorithm to produce some similar words such as "accounttant" and "acountant", "acounttant"

Comment: I'd love to help but I can't understand what you are asking here. An edit to clarify would be good.

Comment: So are you trying to produce "real" words that are similar, or just inserting random characters?  Your two examples show two possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You could compute the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) from the starting word to each word in your vocabulary and pick the 2 or 3 shortest ones.

Depending on how many words are in your dictionary this might take a long time though, so I would recommend bailing out after a certain (small) number of steps - i.e. if you have made 3 mutations and still haven't arrived at your target word then stop and move on to the next one.